# How to overcome AttributeError while attempting to grab iframe table data from a website in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

I am trying to grab table data and found out that its dynamic and from an iframe. My snippet does not work. Any idea of help will be very useful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C://Python38/chromedriver')
browser.get("https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371/top-holders")
url = "https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371/top-holders"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed text-small')
trs = t.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
for tr in trs[:10]:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
browser.quit()
```

Current Output/Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Acer/poocoin.py", line 8, in <module>
trs = t.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpage is dynamic but the table is not a part of any `<iframe>`. The table is a part of the current webpage.

Here I have tried to extract the data from the table you need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371/top-holders'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(8)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed text-small')

# Get all the rows from the table
trs = t.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
```

```
['Address', 'Track Wallet', 'Type', 'Amount', 'Transfer Count', 'Current Balance']
['0xe432afb7283a08be24e9038c30ca6336a7cc8218', 'Contract', '2,047,063,909.1119', '14488', '74,050,430.9257']
['0xa36b9dc17e421d86ddf8e490dafa87344e76125b', 'Track', 'Wallet', '1,000,000,000.0000', '1', '49,463,154.0462']
['0x0eb207b525dc856c3bad5bfd7a7a4aae781e1757', 'Contract', '800,000,000.0000', '1', '3,620,000.0000']
['0xeaed594b5926a7d5fbbc61985390baaf936a6b8d', 'Contract', '150,526,843.9538', '1', '150,000,000.0000']
['0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371', 'Contract', '148,413,174.7757', '14495', '9,165,152.5432']
['0xbbda05ea467ad348212dade5c38c11910c14e83e', 'Track', 'Wallet', '65,442,888.2752', '2093', '61,246,203.1985']
['0x537d90d1d2743f44b65612c9fff3b6f011f65471', 'Track', 'Wallet', '42,871,267.9652', '1', '3,919,432.0622']
['0x2def4d262bc8d7456c8d59138760c992283abf80', 'Track', 'Wallet', '42,411,193.5197', '1', '0.0000']
['0xab2feac90728c278b30c6597760d74eb57b3726f', 'Track', 'Wallet', '42,411,193.5197', '1', '0.0000']
['0xc1e16013a158d57a60d6aa5bb3108722b0ac6df5', 'Contract', '27,101,254.6006', '18', '0.0000']
['0xcfdb8569fb546a010bb22b5057679c4053d4a231', 'Track', 'Wallet', '26,328,593.9564', '7', '11,493,129.6564']
['0x000159831a681a63b01911b9c162fbb8949976ba', 'Contract', '23,385,665.4517', '1', '0.4517']
['0x8f3e8ab6cc8b3d565564256cce95ba9f213c2a0d', 'Track', 'Wallet', '21,880,000.0000', '21', '0.0000']
['0xc590175e458b83680867afd273527ff58f74c02b', 'Contract', '20,386,615.2880', '173', '0.0000']
['0xdb6f1920a889355780af7570773609bd8cb1f498', 'Contract', '19,065,071.3715', '2', '0.0000']
['0x112ac5463b46ba4f32b95ae733f73c6e23bd3e53', 'Track', 'Wallet', '17,982,140.3274', '7', '0.0074']
['0xa8b398896d67cea6d26fc140e056f745261c4b00', 'Track', 'Wallet', '17,933,245.4310', '21', '9,024,167.7594']
['0x2368b6acc957339cf34a08a064830fcdfcac02c6', 'Track', 'Wallet', '17,675,714.5003', '1', '8.5003']
['0x7cacd11be7d7c95c48a0477875d31040ddaff2da', 'Track', 'Wallet', '17,467,065.9791', '1', '0.0000']
['0xc62184ac04a0610147bd890ba32d1918b67e017c', 'Track', 'Wallet', '16,841,462.6819', '1', '2.6819']
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but what is the best method to convert this into(formatted string) or this output format `code` 0x000159831a681a63b01911b9c162fbb8949976ba Contract  23,385,665.4517 1 0.4517

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is that the page renders iframe in a separate call, and so the standard Soup call isn't finding it.

Given you're importing selenium, have you tried [switch_to()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to)?
Once you've switched to the iframe, you can call .page_source(), and use this as your bs4 input.

```
browser.switch_to.frame(your_frame_name)
r = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed text-small')
trs = t.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
for tr in trs[:10]:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Tried it, getting selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException Error.

Comment: Ok - just had a look at the actual website. I have a feeling its taking a few seconds to render.
Try removing browser.switch_to.frame(your_frame_name), and replacing it with time.sleep(8).
Will need to add import time

Comment: still having AttributeError